# How to reverse code responses for a certain variable?

Tags: r, return-value

I'm trying to reverse the coding of the responses on this question so I can put them into an index with other variables. I am trying to make the 1s into 5s, 5s into 1, 2s into 4s, and 4s into 2s. 3s need to stay 3s. Here is what I have been trying, but I have been unsuccessful so far.

```
# how easily do you make decisions (1 can make decisions easily, 5 not easily)
decisive <- DfP_CH$GENDERPERSONALITY_DECISIONS
# need to recode this for masc index
install.packages("car")
library(car)
decisive_revcode <- recode(decisive, 1==5,2==4,4==2,5==1)
View(decisive_revcode)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372866/reverse-score-a-vector

Comment: `DfP_CH$decisive_rev <- 6 - DfP_CH$decisive`?

Comment: Thank you so much!! Wow I way overthought that